# Delphi XE5 - components initialization on start-up

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

I'd like to set some of my `RadioButton`s and `Checkbox`es true or false on start-up of my application... but when I did it in `OnShow`, `OnActivate` or `OnCreate` events handlers I get exceptions, and even whole form isn't painted (lack of many controls on form).

Have you got any good practice to do this?

Comment: Yes. Remove bugs in your code (by using debugger).

Comment: oncreate event may have this, but onshow event cant produce this kind of problem do you use custom drawing? if not then try to create a demo project drop couple of check boxes and set them to true on Form OnShow event if the problem will repeat then theres something wrong with your IDE if not then the problem is in the Code without which we cannot say much also next time try to paste the stack trace :)

Comment: And your code is ?  SSCEE ? and what exactly exceptions say ? at least their type ? http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: I think it was TStyleBook issue. I'm new to it, sometimes make stupid mistakes

Comment: @user30993174444, TStyleBook is located on the Firemonkey platform, that would be called releveant information that should be included in your original post.

Answer (score 5):

Which event you choose to use depends on when you want the action to execute.

- `OnCreate` executes once only during the lifetime of the form.
- `OnShow` executes every time the form goes from hidden to showing. Potentially it can execute many times during the lifetime of the form.
- `OnActivate` executes every time the form form receives focus. Potentially it can execute many times during the lifetime of the form.

The controls that are defined in the .dfm file are all instantiated by the time each of these events fires.

So, on the face of it, of these choices, `OnCreate` is probably the most logical choice for initialization code. But only you can know for sure when you want this code to run.

As for the exceptions that you encounter, they are because your code contains bugs. Since we cannot see your code, you'll need to debug the code without our help.